# Are there any software to build and 3D simulate an entire audio visual live show?

Tags: performing, algorithmic-composition, live, ableton-live

I know you can mix visuals with: resolume

I know you can create and perform electronic music with: Ableton

And I know you can design and perform light shows with: Sunlite Suite.

I also know softwares like quartz composer, max and touch designer that let you create and perform generative visuals; also interfacing with hardware like arduino.

But...

Is there a software where you can design and simulate and entire Audio, Light and Visual and then perform it before getting on the real stage ?

A show like this:

Otherwise; how big companies like Ultra or Immersive do ?

The should have a system to preproduce the live show in some way before getting into the venue and assembling it

any suggestions ?

Comment: Ableton offers [support for video](https://www.ableton.com/en/manual/working-with-video/) editing alongside audio production. Not sure if it's exactly what you are looking for, but it's probably worth a look.

Comment: Nope for video editing I use premiere and after effects.  I'm looking for an all in one solution to build and simulate in 3D a live show like the one above

Answer (score 3):

There is no solution that does audio and video and light.

It's very, very expensive and time-consuming to pre-produce an entire show. Aside from preparation cost, you also have to factor in that all the needed equipment should be brought on tour as well. Most touring DJs cannot afford this and also cannot permit to lock down their playlist. There are a few exceptions ( Daft Punk, Amon Tobin and Deadmaus come to mind ), but festivals like Ultra are for the most part improvised using traditional audio, video and light equipment and software.

The DJ will mix records on Traktor or Pioneer CDJs. The light, video, laser, pyro and CO2 operators will then improvise along to this, each using their own hardware and software. They will have a wide range of material and presets prepared, some of it just for that show, and use these at the right time.

Some DJs ( the top of the DJ Mag top 100 ) travel with a LD and / or VJ, that bring custom material for that DJ and know the DJ's playlist particularly well.
On such tours, occasionally SMPTE is used to sync the visual and light show exactly to a track, but for the most part the big festivals like Ultra and Tomorrowland are improvised on the spot by the operators.